# Explain the structure of spring project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite

I am new to Spring and just created a project using Spring CLI.

When I opened the project using STS i see the following folder structure.
There are two `src` folders.

What is the difference between them ? `src/main/java` and just `src`.

Also suppose I want to create a new folder like `webapp` under `main`, where should I create it ?
I looked a lot online but couldn't find any answers.

Please help.

[image]

Comment: See [Maven Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

Comment: There's [docs for this on the Maven website](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There are two src folders

No, it's just one `src` folder and what you see is a way of displaying a Maven project under **Package Explorer** view of eclipse/STS. Change the view to **Navigator** and you find that it's just one `src` folder.

Comment: Thanks you so much

Answer (score 4):

If you want to create a new folder "webapp", please don't. If you use Spring, you won't need it !
How you should read this project:

- `src/main/java` is where you write your .java files that will go in production
- `src/main/resources` is where you will put your *.properties file (mostly) and other files, that are not .java files.
- `src/test/java` is where you write your .java file that will run tests against your `src/main/java/**.java` files.
- `target` is where your java files will be compiled. You will find your .classes file, but also the files inside `src/main/resources`. Those files will be inside your .jar when you decide to create one.

You think you see 2 `src` folder, but in reality, it is your IDE that gives you this. If you go on your file system, I am sure you will have only one `src` folder. It is your IDE, thanks you maven and some default configuration, which "flags" different folder in category, to be able to compile and run your tests. There is 4 categories :

- `sources`: `src/main/java`
- `resources`: `src/main/resources`
- `Test sources`: `src/test/java`
- `Test resources`: `src/test/resources` (sometimes)

If you to build a webapp using Spring, go read this: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-tutorial. It is well explained, and you will be able to run a project in a short time.